# How to create pentagon shape for avatar image?

Tags: css, html, css-shapes

I can't figure out how to create pentagon shape for user avatar image (or .svg).

Looking for shape that point down not top.

I have found examples here http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ but don't know how to 
fill image in such shape. Background propertie also won't work, stuck here.

[Pentagon example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81qkB.jpg)

Comment: You could apply a CSS transform (`transform: rotate(180deg);`) and rotate the hexagon from css tricks.

Comment: The SVG answers provided are probably the way to go. If you need older browser support, probably the only way would be a png mask placed over the normal image. The png would match whatever background you're using, and have a pentagon shaped hole in the middle that you'd see the avatar through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest solution without any CSS, would be using `svg`(maximum browser support).

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="-1 0 101 100">
  <path d="M20,0 L80,0 L100,60 L50,100 L0,60z" stroke="black" fill="coral" />
</svg>
```

---

You can define inline `svg` `clipPath` and apply `svg` clipping on an `image`. This has way better browser support than CSS `clip-path`.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M20,0 L80,0 L100,60 L50,100 L0,60z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="https://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" x="0" y="0" height="100px" width="100px" />
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks, I haven't knew about svg. But how to insert there image in .png or .jpg formats?

Comment: @user2791999 - Check out the edit. Sorry! Misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a clip-path

[**CSS-Tricks Link**](http://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/)

```css
div {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/300);
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 38%, 82% 100%, 18% 100%, 0% 38%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 38%, 82% 100%, 18% 100%, 0% 38%);
}
/* Center the demo */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Just offering choices. I prefer an SVG too.

Comment: I'm not arguing with you. SVG is better IMO too...just stating choices.

Comment: Sorry if it was offensive. Did not mean to be. Was just saying that CSS `clip-path` has a horrible browser support.

Comment: Agreed...support is bad **at the moment** but it's coming.

Comment: This - `polygon(50% 0%, 100% 38.2%, 80.9% 100%, 19.1% 100%, 0% 38.2%)` would be the coordinates with as much accuracy as possible to create a regular pentagon (perhaps for a 3D transform). Second demicals are zero in all cases. If my calculations are correct, which they appear to be, then some of the numbers are 19% and 81% rather than 18% and 82% but that's nitpicking for the current question involved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
#pentagon {
    position: relative;
    width: 54px;
    border-width: 0 18px 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red transparent;
}
#pentagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    top: 50px;
    left: -18px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 45px 45px 0 45px;
border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
}

.logo-sponsor{
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 36px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="pentagon">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/43-twitter-48.png" class="logo-sponsor">
</div>
```