# Create pentagon shape css :before with background image

Tags: html, css

I need to create a "div top" with a pentagon shape with a background inside.
Is this possible with CSS3? I have tried a number of things with not success. This is the code I am currently left with:

```css
.sectionDIVHead:before {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  content: " ";
  background-size: 50% 80%;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 95px);
  margin-top: -5%;
  background-position: bottom;
  border-left: 52px solid transparent;
  border-right: 54px solid transparent;
  background-image: url("../images/Icon.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, #000 50%, transparent 51%)0% 100%/50.5% 70px no-repeat, linear-gradient(to top right, #000 50%, transparent 51%)100% 100%/50% 70px no-repeat;
  padding: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create pentagon shape for avatar image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381057/how-to-create-pentagon-shape-for-avatar-image)

Comment: @achref really? Can you please explain how?

Comment: The comment says "Possible duplicate" not "Definitely is a duplicate". I suggested it because you might find a solution in the above link, if you don't, you can just ignore it.

Comment: I had tried it, doesn't work, tried all them I could find, that is why I posted a new question.